# SSIS Package, works on one server and not on another. Logon denied

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package which gathers data from Oracle and puts it into SQL. This package runs fine on the current server. However when I run the same package, which was exported to a file system, on another server it fails with the error ORA-1005 - null password given; logon denied.

I can connect to Oracle from the server and also to SQL. The weird thing is, if I navigate to the new server from the old server using windows explorer and run the package it works fine. It is only failing when executed from the new server, works fine when executed from the old server even though the file is on the new server.

Please can someone help as this is driving me nuts!

Thanks

Comment: This is  ODBC Oracle connection or you connect direct from SSIS package where you enter server name, choose database http://www.mssqltips.com/tipimages2/2091_connection_manager.JPG ?

Comment: connect direct from SSIS package. I have the source set as the Oracle server and the destination set as the SQL.

Comment: So if window is like in my first comment, when you enter all info and push "Test Connection". Succesfull or not? :)

Comment: the connection test is successful. It's when I execute the package does it fail. But like I said, when I navigate to the same file using the old server it works fine. It's only on the new server that the errors appears.

Comment: Ok that and should be, the test succesfull and when you execute he loose passwords

Comment: How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from our little chat I'm guessing that SSIS packages lossing passwords for connections in the servers. You need to use config file for the connection string properties (with username and password included) and it will work probably.

In your SSIS package

1. SSIS->Package Configurations mark enable
2. Add->Next-> Specify conf settings directly choose your location and name of config file->Save
3. In tab Objects find your connection and expand->Properties_>Mark "ConnectionString", "Name","Password"
4. Next Next

Sometimes configuration file too dont save password. So after creating configuration file go and open it with notepad. When you enter your pass and save, **this should be done when package is closed**.

Example of config file(don't copy create your own):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><DTSConfiguration><DTSConfigurationHeading>
<DTSConfigurationFileInfo GeneratedBy="dasdsa\dasdsa" 
GeneratedFromPackageName="Package" 
GeneratedFromPackageID="{53B24B50-B43F-4D51-AD15-44FC92896BCA}"
 GeneratedDate="27.11.2012 19:07:35"/></DTSConfigurationHeading>
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" 
Path="\Package.Connections[Oracle].Properties[Name]" ValueType="String">
<ConfiguredValue>YourName
</ConfiguredValue></Configuration><Configuration 
ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections
[Oracle].Properties[Password]"
 ValueType="String"><ConfiguredValue>**ENTERHEREPASS**</ConfiguredValue>
</Configuration></DTSConfiguration>
```

**2. Part. Why Agent Job fail executing package**
When transferring from one server to another 
There could be several problems:

1. Need to set up right executing mode 64 or 32 bit http://www.bidn.com/blogs/ShawnHarrison/ssis/2362/ssis-basics-running-a-package-in-32-bit-mode
2. Security set on package "ProtectionLevel" can do bad things
3. Sql server Agent Job is running under the Owner rights which have **no rights**.

Comment: Hi Justin, can yu advise on how best to do this?

Comment: one other thing, when i now run this as a scheduled job it fails with error:DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  15:40:40  Finished: 15:40:40  Elapsed:  0.296 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Comment: this is not error:) go in "Job Activity Monitor" choose failed Job right mouse button "View history"->expand your failed job and mark failed step. In tab in the bottom there is info about error. Copy all info from Message row. http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-r-j0-287cFc/T8jP-r3vWlI/AAAAAAAAAaE/ptsILj5kQPM/s1600/JobHistory.jpg

Comment: Date  27/11/2012 15:40:40
Log  Job History (1 Minute Import of Alarms and Alarm Calls Data SPH)

Step ID  1
Server  CNSVSQL01
Job Name  1 Minute Import of Alarms and Alarm Calls Data SPH
Step Name  1 Minute Import Alarms Call Data From Service Director
Duration  00:00:00
Sql Severity  0
Sql Message ID  0
Operator Emailed  
Operator Net sent  
Operator Paged  
Retries Attempted  0

Message

Comment: Executed as user: COFFEENATION\SQLAdmin. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.2500.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  15:40:40  Error: 2012-11-27 15:40:40.91     Code: 0xC0047062     Source: Data Flow Task 1 Source - Query [1]     Description: System.Exception: OCIEnvCreate failed with return code -1 but error message text was not available.

Comment: at System.Data.OracleClient.OciHandle..ctor(OciHandle parentHandle, HTYPE handleType, MODE ocimode, HANDLEFLAG handleflags)     at System.Data.OracleClient.OciEnvironmentHandle..ctor(MODE environmentMode, Boolean unicode)     at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName)     at

Comment: Maybe Edit your question and put al in one piece in question

Comment: System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString connectionOptions)     at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)     at

Comment: System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)     at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open()     at

Comment: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ManagedHelper.GetManagedConnection(String assemblyQualifiedName, String connStr, Object transaction)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManager100.AcquireConnection(Object pTransaction)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DataReaderSourceAdapter.AcquireConnections(Object transaction)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostAcquireConnections(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Object transaction)  End Error  Error: 2012-11-27 15:40:40.91

Comment: Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "Source - Query" (1) failed validation and returned error code 0x80131500.  End Error  Error: 2012-11-27 15:40:40.91     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2012-11-27 15:40:40.91     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task 1      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  15:40:40

Comment: which security you set on your ssis package?

Comment: encryptsensitivewithuserkey

Comment: What you need to do. change or disable maybe for test security on SSIS when run Job. If not, there could be that when you create jor Job there is Owner of Job(in first window) this owner maybe don't have permisions to run Package on the server... If this not maybe you transfer your package from 32 bit server to 64 bit server, you neeed to set in Job, Step properties that this Package run at 32 bit:)

Comment: you are correct the first server was 32 bit and the new is 64 bit. When i set to run in 32 bit, it gives me the error:
Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.

Comment: The package must be not in Desktop, In C:/ssis/ something like this. Open package in solution explor and set this to True  or false... http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/files/2012/06/ssis6.jpg

Comment: i've also changed the security to DontSaveSensitive

Comment: Ok so if there in package is set to 32 bit you must set and in Job step properties tu run 32 bit and vice versa if not working. here http://www.bidn.com/blogs/ShawnHarrison/ssis/2362/ssis-basics-running-a-package-in-32-bit-mode

Comment: I cannot set to false as I don't have the project only the dtsx file which i exported from the live server. The project was created by another guy who was here before me...

Comment: if this not working there is another solution to create very simple package on new server and try to run by agent if agent will fail then the owner of the Job don't have permissions to run packages, you need set your user, because the sql server agent has default rights.

Comment: I'm think you can import dtsx file in the BI Visual studio .... I'm now leaving. Like I say there is two problems running on on 64 bit server or agent job don't have permissions to run package.

Comment: Please put updates in the question and the answer; the comments are delving into the area of making this an unwieldy question/answer for future users.  I'm cleaning out the comments within the next day, so please move the information you want to keep to either the question (if it's a clarification, code, or stacktrace), or the answer (if it improves the answer).